How to build AOSP 13 at Intel 285k without errors
got constant crash with build AOSP 13 at intel 285k and 265k. (total different hardware set with different MB and memory)
OS: Ubuntu 22 
kernel: 6.8.0-49 
RAM: 96 Gb + 32 Gb swap, used only 50 Gb during build
command for download and build:
echo "start download $(date)" && \
repo init --depth=1 --no-tags --current-branch -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0_r83 && \
repo sync --current-branch --no-clone-bundle --no-tags && \
echo "start building $(date)" && \
rm -rf out &&\
source build/envsetup.sh && \
lunch aosp_arm64-eng && \
export LC_ALL=C && \
sed -i 's#!/usr/bin/python.*#!/usr/bin/python2#g' device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py && \
make -j$(nproc --all)

may be anyone know how to fix it ?
same task on 13900k with the same memory working without any problems
memory passed all tests - ok 
AOSP 10 compiling without problems, problem for now in compiling only AOSP 13
may be problem in all arrrow lakes?
can someone retest it at your hardware ?




Exactly how much RAM do you have? If you have less than 128 GiB you should definitely turn on ZRAM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79037240/is-it-possible-to-build-aosp-on-32gb-ram/79040397#79040397

@satur9nine 96 Gb RAM, only 50 Gb used during build, again 13900k with 32 build threads ok, but 285k with 24 build threads not ok. Looking like crash happen at extended instructions use

If something tried to run an instruction your CPU didn't support, you'd get SIGILL not SIGSEGV.  Can't copy/paste from the image of code, but the fault address might be non-canonical.  Looks like too many hex digits, not 48-bit sign-extended.  It might or might not be 57-bit sign-extended with PML5, if your kernel is using that.
